# How to show two images for comparison in SP2013 Online

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365

We use Office 365 and SharePoint 2013 Online.

I would like to have a single image library (or asset library if necessary) where the user editing Image 1 can go to a lookup field, select from names of the other images in the same library, and choose Image 2. In a custom view, the user would see the list of thumbnails and alongside would be the thumbnail (not the full-size image) of the selected lookup image to compare. I'm having trouble getting access to & using the thumbnail's URL in a clean/simple way, basically.

Am I destined for a third party app? Suggestions?

Comment: I started with a manual copy/paste of the URL of the referenced image into a custom hyperlink-as-image field of the primary image's record, but it was a serious hassle trying to find the URL for the thumbnail as opposed to the full size image, not to mention being highly manual. I don't know much about doing workflows, but I would imagine that I could have a workflow that *puts* the thumbnail URL into a text field when an image record is created - but I haven't been able to figure that out yet. Using a second library didn't really solve the problem either.

Comment: You can do a workflow or use CSR.  Thumbnail url follow the following format: if the image url is `/image library/folder/imagename.jpg`, then the thumbnail url will be `/image library/folder/_t/imagename_jpg.jpg`.

Comment: @wjervis Do you know what the address would be of the square thumbnails used in media/asset libraries? Or are those made on the fly? That worked perfectly to get the regular one- thank you!!

Comment: I haven't found anything online, and I haven't the time to experiment right now, sorry.

Comment: No worries - just wondering if you had it handy. I will keep looking. Thank you very much. As soon as I find a sleek solution I'll post it.